# Keycloak - allow linking of 2 accounts with different emails

Tags: keycloak

I need to implement a login flow with KeyCloak where a user will be prompted to reauthenticate with an existing account (by email/password or via social IdP) after authentication with a non-existing social  account OR choose to create a new KeyCloak account.

Something like on the picture below:

[image]

Is it possible to implement such a flow with KeyCloak?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that flow with regular Identity Providers feature in Keycloak

0. Overview Steps
   detail information [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/social-login.html)

[image]

**1. IDP URL**
{keyclaok URL}/realms/{realm}/broker/{idp name}/endpoint

example:
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/broker/stackoverflow/endpoint

**2.  Register Application at Social App**
example: StackOverflow  https://stackapps.com/
[image]

**3. Get Client Information from Social App**
example: StackOverflow
[image]

**4. Set IDP at Keycloak**
[image]

**5. Test**

5.1 Before add user
[image]
5.2 login by Social
[image]
5.3 Update user account (set password and e-mail)
[image]
[image]
5.4 check added user
[image]

5.5 Test added user login by username/password OR
Social Icon Click without credential
[image]

5.6 logged in test by both ways
[image]

5.7 Picked up e-mail from Facebook and detect e-mail already exists.
[image]

5.8 I select "Add to existing account" then filled out e-mail and password from Keycloak.
[image]

Comment: I don't think the answer covers the following case: **User A**  has an existing Keycloak account (email: **acc1@email.com**). **User A** logs in with a social IdP, but that social user account tight to different email **acc2@email.com**.  Based on your answer,  the Keycloak will automatically create new account with email **acc2@email.com** which is wrong as per the diagram presented in the question. Instead of automatically creating account, Keycloak should suggests user two options: 1) Link this new account to existing one or 2) create new account.

Comment: When new user to register in Update Account Information after social IdP, Keyclock picked up username, First name and Last name from IdP. the e-mail not pickiup that time. user can decide using same as IdP email or other e-mail. Either way allow by Keycloak but have enter e-mail address. Then he/she need to add password. If yes, shows "Please re-authenticate to continue" for password or  he/she can login by click the Idp button without credential. 1) Link this new account to existing option gives a two choice one is using same e-mail of IdP or new e-mail, 2)Create new account is support itself

Comment: @BenchVue thanks for your answer! Unfortunatly, rigjht now based on your answer I don't see how it is possible with KeyCloak to link 2 different social accounts (for example fom LinkedIn and Facebook) under the same user KeyCloak account. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @alexanoid, I tested facebook. it picked up my e-mail as a username but LinkedIn do not support localhost redirect URL. I can't test LinkedIn. You want to picked up the same e-mail from two different social IdP if user has same e-mail?

Comment: No, I’d like to be able to link 2 different social accounts with different emails under the same single KeyCloak account. Or create a new account. KeyCloak should provide the choice to the user what to do.

Comment: How to know the different e-mail is a same user? I tested Facebook and Github. Both picked up same e-mail and detect duplicate user same e-mail and shows e-mail as a username. I updated my answer.

Comment: by reauthentication. User sees the screen where KeyCloak for example asks to reathenticate with a previously registered account (via username/password or social login) in order to link OR KeyCloak asks to create a brand new account. All of that on the same screen. This is exactly the crux of my question here.

Comment: "2 different social accounts with different emails" is no way to detect is same user. From my experimental, only detect "2 different social accounts with same emails" is same user.

Comment: you don't need to detect it automatically. You are just logged in, for example via Google. KeyCloak sees that this is new social account  (by google ID) and asks you what do you want to do now - 1. Would like to link this Google account with an existent KeyCloak account? Then you have to log in into this existent account on KeyCloak in order to confirm that you are owner of both accounts (new and existent) 2. Or KeyCloak asks you to create a brand-new account. Is this possible with KeyCloak?

Comment: I tested google iDP too. After IdP setting in Keycloak. #1 If login first time, Keycloak Shows Google Icon. #2 Shows picked up my google e-mail automatically. #3 Click my google email, automatically create new account with google email as new username. So your question 1. not ask to create new account.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication flows within Keycloak can be customized (virtually all of the flows can be customized or extended).  I believe you'll need to implement a custom Authentication SPI (Service Provider Interface).  This will be a JAR that you can add custom logic upon account creation.

Here's the [Keycloak documentation for SPIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi).